# How to add a skill field in a job form using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to add a skill field in a job form using codeigniter like SO tag search ?
[image]
Should I use a specific plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
[Bootstrap select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html). its very simple take a look at their [examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to add skills have to be done on front end, so there is no way to do it in codeigniter. You can use jQuery [Plugin](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) for this purpose, or you can use AngularJS to make on your on ( the simple way ).